# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'", but I have installed NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to run CNN code, which needs NumPy module. Although I've installed NumPy, the following error occurs: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'"

Python 3.7, Running on Windows 10 64-bit, installed pip through pip

I've reinstalled Numpy and fixed the location, but it wasn't working.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed in your system?

Comment: Make sure you are using the same python environment when executing the file and when installing. You can use `python/python3/python3.7 -m pip install numpy`

Comment: @Tiendung yes, but in case I did it wrong, could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: @DPS No. I've gotten only Python 3.7

Comment: @JonathanPeters first check your user PATH, refer [this link](https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/)

Comment: @Tiendung I did, but same error occurs